# Google maps overlapping using vue2-google-maps

Tags: vue.js, maps, marker, overlapping, vue2-google-maps

In my project some markers has the same lat and lng so they overlapping,
I'm using this package vue2-google-maps for google maps.

How i can show for example on map a number, shows how many markers are overlapping ?
Or any solution would help.

Thank you.